# How load a txt file using ClassLoader?

Tags: java, resources, classloader

I have the following code:

```
 public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.properties"));
     System.out.println(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt"));
     System.out.println(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));
     System.out.println(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
     System.out.println(App.class.getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));
     System.out.println(App.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
   }
 }
```

This code gives the following output:

```
file:/C:/../test.properties 
null 
java.io.BufferedInputStream@18e2b22 
null 
java.io.BufferedInputStream@1cb1c5fa 
null
```

Why does ClassLoader refuses to load .txt file?

Updated:

**I'm sure that both of my files in the classpath. Classpath is set to /src and both files are in this directory.**

Comment: is the text file on your classpath?

Comment: Please use code formatting on input/output (as well as just code).

Comment: There is no reason why you should not be able to load a text file via the classloader (incidentally you would normally use the context classloader). There is some sort of error in how you have setup your classpath - you just haven't spotted it yet. Are test.proeprties and test.txt in the same directory (ie same actual directory, not just a common root)? Do you have other files names test.properties on your classpath - if so could it be these that are being resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your txt file is not on the classpath

Comment: Intellij Idea doesn't move files from source folder with other extensions into classpath. It moves only property files. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure that any file you want to load using `ClassLoader` is included in your `classpath`. Normally resources like that are stored in `/src/main/resources` which is then included in the classpath.

If you're using Eclipse you can right click on the project in the explorer and go to `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source (Tab) -> Add Folder... (Button)` and add the folder structure in there.